# Dealing with data from multiple individual spreadsheets. Should data be merged OR are there better ways to deal with multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, import

I have transactional data (spreadsheets) from different time periods and would like to know if there are better ways to import the data to a mastersheet, than to merge all the spreadsheets into one? If I merge the data, I will have to append items to this master document in the future which could be an option, but am wondering if there are methods to consider?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there. You can put all data in tabs in the same spreadsheet file. Explain clearly whether the data is actually in separate spreadsheet files or all in the same spreadsheet file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`importrange()`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340) function to merge data from multiple spreadsheet files into a master spreadsheet. It would look something like this:

```
=query( 
  { 
    importrange("spreadsheet id 1", "Sheet1!A1:F"); 
    importrange("spreadsheet id 2", "Sheet1!A2:F"); 
    importrange("spreadsheet id 3", "Sheet1!A2:F"); 
    importrange("spreadsheet id 4", "Sheet1!A2:F") 
  }, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 
  1 
)
```

The results will automatically update every 30 minutes, and usually much more often. They will be view-only.

If the data is stored in tabs in the same spreadsheet file, and the master sheet is in the same spreadsheet file as well, do not use `importrange()` but an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276).